# get FB cookies automatically (javascript, php ?)

Tags: facebook, cookies

I'm trying to find a way to get the cookies that facebook generates when you log in. Like when I go to chrome://settings/cookies and search for facebook.com - there are many cookies, e.g. c_user. I found a lot of stuff that connect with node.js to facebook USING these cookies, but what I want is the other way around:
get the cookies of any facebook accounts I have e-mail and password with a program.

Thanks for any Help, an idea would be great,
David

Comment: Why? And you can only have email and password to one Facebook account without breaking Facebook Terms of Service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this. Browsers do not allow things like this for security purposes.

You can only get the values of cookies that were set by the current domain.